# Python export Database query result as JSON for Calendar JS

Tags: python, json, flask, sqlalchemy

I am querying my Database to then return the values and JSONIFY them into JSON format so that the "fullcalendar js" can parse them and show them on my front end.

My model of the DB is as follows :

```
class database(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
userid = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
user = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
startdate = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
enddate = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
duration = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
approved = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
```

The JSON format i need them to be is :

```
[
  {
    "title": "Long Event",
    "start": "2014-09-07",
    "end": "2014-09-10"
  }
]
```

What i have tried ("And failed!")

```
alldata = database.query.filter(database.approved == True).all()

events = {"title": [], "start": [], "end": []};

for row in alldata:
    events["title"].append(row.user.strip("[]"))
    events["start"].append(datetime.datetime.strptime(row.startdate,'%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d').strip("[]"))
    events["end"].append(datetime.datetime.strptime(row.enddate, '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d').strip("[]"))

# Serializing json
json_object = json.dumps(events, indent=4)
jsontoreturn="["+json_object+"]"
return jsontoreturn
```

The reason this fails is the resulting JSON is in the format of :

```
[{
"title": [
    "Ben"
],
"start": [
    "2021-12-29"
],
"end": [
    "2021-12-31"
]
}]
```

As you can see the Dictionary is adding Sqaure brackets and as a result the FullCalendar JS (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) doesnt parse it correctly and fails.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the ability to actually test this against your value for `alldata` but I suspect the following will work:

```
alldata = database.query.filter(database.approved == True).all()

def process_row(row):
    # func which returns a dictionary like:
    # {"title": "Long Event", "start": "2014-09-07", "end": "2014-09-10" }
    return dict (title = row.user.strip("[]"),
                 start = datetime.datetime.strptime(row.startdate,'%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d').strip("[]"),
                 end = datetime.datetime.strptime(row.enddate, '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d').strip("[]"),
                 )

# Make a list of dictionaries based on the input, `alldata`
events = [process_row(r) for r in alldata]
```

Then simply:

```
json_object = json.dumps(events, indent=4)

return json_object
```

OR, if you want to use Flask's `jsonify` function which also sets the `Content-Type` header:

```
return jsonify(events)
```

Comment: This works as expained, I appreciate the comments explaining what each step does. Accepted as answer!

Comment: @benfamily2 No probs.  Not sure why someone downvoted your question, as it meets SO requirements more than most others: Shows the problem ✅ Expected output ✅ What you tried ✅ Incorrect output ✅.  Happy this has worked for you!